# How to notify user on job completed

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I would like to display a popup when job is finished.

I have servlet which is using executor for executing long jobs. Tasks can take 20 minutes how can I display popup when job is completed to any jsp view where user is right this time(session)?

For example user submitting form in servlet job is submitted to executor, servlet send some response and redirect to /view1 user is using another modules of web (/view2 /view3 etc), when job is completed and user is at /viewX he in the middle of page get popup "Your task *SUPER TASK* has finished".

I know it's possible to do because this mechanism is implemented in Jira atlasian 
Thank You in advance

Comment: Could you paste a few lines of how you start the job in executor? In particular, if you are using executor API from atlassian? Or creating your own executor?

Comment: First i create Executor from java.util.concurrent.Executor; ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); at app start, and than submiting tasks: executorService.submit(()->{}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality shouldn't be done in JSP or servlet, you could write few lines of javascript that will periodically ask a server for a status of the job. When the job is done it should display the popup.
If for whatever reason you prefer to do it in JSP then the user will only get the popup if he refreshes the page.

Comment: I think its the best way. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use promises using JS.
Send new promise, it's as async request, and when job is completed, you get a result or error, if something was wrong.

Please have a look at https://codeburst.io/javascript-learn-promises-f1eaa00c5461 (or just type 'js promise')